# Wordpress - how to query for a user based on meta_value vs user input

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am using Ultimate Member plugin to store and display users within our new intranet site. I have been asked if we could develop a search bar where HR can type in a car registration and it will return the user's profile. A user may have multiple cars and these are stored as meta key - numberplate1, 2 , 3 etc.

I have been told that I must use a custom query to achieve this. This is my attempt so far where I am trying to write custom SQL which is returning the user's name when I hard-code a number plate in PHPMyAdmin:

```
add_filter( 'um_prepare_user_query_args', 'um_user_before_query_usrs', 10, 2 );
function um_user_before_query_usrs( $query, $directory_data ){

    global $current_user;
    global $current_user_Location;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

 if (!is_admin() && user_can( $current_user, "administrator")){

$searchterm = $_POST['search']. '*';
$sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.display_name FROM wp_users, wp_usermeta
WHERE wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = {'$searchterm}'";

echo $sqlquery;

$usernames = array();
$nameArray = array();
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results($sqlquery);
echo $usernames;
$query->set('users', $usernames);
}
return $query;
}
```

However, this does not seem to be working. The echo's are also not displaying which isnt helpful. Is this the correct way to get the user's input into the search?

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can achieve this?

Thanks!